# Using jQuery to fade between two divs, images work, iframes don't

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, transition, fade

*Edit:* Uploaded live, [with images](http://www.vitalitypilates.com/tabtest/tabtest1), and [with iframes](http://www.vitalitypilates.com/tabtest/tabtest2)

I'm trying to make `pane1` fade into `pane2`. It works with images, but I'm wanting to do it with iframes. Is this possible? Any input is greatly appreciated.

**JS is such:**

```
$(function() {
$("#tab ul").tabs("#panes > div", {effect: 'fade', fadeOutSpeed: 400});
});
```

**HTML is such:**

```
<div id="tab">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#1">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#2">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[...]

```
<div id="panes">
    <div>
        <iframe src="pane1.html" width="720" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <iframe src="pane2.html" width="720" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" />
    </div>
</div>
```

On load the `pane1` iframe is displayed as expected and clicking `Tab 2` fades it out, but it fades into nothing.

However, it works perfectly using the exact same code as above, but with images in the div:

```
<div id="panes">
    <div>
        <img src="images/pane1.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/pane2.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant CSS

```
#tab ul {   
    width:720px;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    left: 0;
}

#tab li {   
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-top:0px;
    }

#tab a {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #5472c0;
    }   

#tab a.current {
    color: #272f80;
    }

#panes {
    position:relative;
    height: 212px;
    left: 50%;
    width:720px;
    margin-left: -360px;
    margin-top: 16px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

*Edit:* Uploaded live, [with images](http://www.vitalitypilates.com/tabtest/tabtest1), and [with iframes](http://www.vitalitypilates.com/tabtest/tabtest2)

Comment: It would help if you posted a link to a working version of the page on GitHub.  I'm not able to get this working with the code that you've provided.

Comment: I'm uploading it live right now.

Comment: If you inspect the HTML using Firebug or developer tools, you see in the iframe example that it removes the div for the second tab from the markup altogether, rather than just hiding it. This is probably the problem. Why, however, I have no idea. Might be a bug with the plugin used.

Comment: @AndrewR I just checked your live sample in Chrome (15.0.874.106) and the iframe sample simply fades to white. From what I read, this isn't the desired effect... Just checking to confirm. I get the impression it's not working.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for responding, you are correct. As Brian pointed out, it was simply the close tag on the iFrame.

Comment: @AndrewR Haha wow, sorry. I totally misunderstood your edit - I thought it was an edit to say 'Here it is live and working now' rather than to say 'Here's my broken stuff'. Oh well, better safe than sorry. I'll read more next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have a CLUE as to why this works, but if you end the iFrames with a full tag, it seems to work.

```
    <div id="here">
        <iframe src="http://www.vitalitypilates.com/tabtest/pane1.html" width="720" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="gone">
        <iframe src="http://www.vitalitypilates.com/tabtest/pane2.html" width="720" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
```